# urxvt Open new tab with the same current directory as the current tab

Tags: rxvt

Whenever a new tab is opened in urxvt, the cwd(current working directory) is the default directory set in bashrc.

How to make the new tab to be opened at the cwd of the current tab?

Comment: to do this, one should tell rxvt about the cwd of the shell running in it somehow. i imagine an rxvt plugin hooking up to new-tab event (if there is such), looking into the cwd of current tab's child process (if it's exposed to the plugin api) in `/proc/PID/cwd` maybe, then chdir to it in the main process context, then let the new-tab routine to run, then chdir back in the new-tab post-event hook (if any).

Comment: You could twiddle with your `.bashrc` to open _every_ new shell in the last visited directory.

Comment: @hedgie How would we do that?

Answer (score 1):

First, you could override the `cd` builtin with a function that stores the current directory every time you change a directory.

```
cd() {
    command cd $@
    pwd > ~/.curdir
}
```

Then, you could change to this last known directory in every new shell you open:

```
command cd `cat ~/.curdir`
```

If you place both these snippets in your `~/.bashrc`, every new shell you open with have the overridden `cd` command and will try to change to the last known directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd() {
    command cd $@
    pwd > ~/.curdir
}

command cd `cat ~/.curdir`
```

Note that I used the `command` builtin to gain access to the original `cd` command instead of the function named `cd()`. Also note that doing this will probably have unintended side effects, especially when you have multiple shells open at the same time (which is kind of the whole point of using `urxvt` tabs).